# Getting postgreSQL binaries without third party tools

Tags: postgresql, license

Where can I download postgreSQL binaries without third party tools like pgAdmin, stackbuilder?

From licencing point of view, can I download binaries from https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries and delete pgAdmin, stackbuilder folders and distribute the remaining folders with my product?

Is there any other source where I can download only postgreSQL binaries for linux?

Comment: Can you distribute it? Yes absolutely. Postgres (and the tools) are released under  [the PostgreSQL Licence](http://www.postgresql.org/about/licence) which essentially lets you do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using? For Debian and Ubuntu you should be using the official APT repository, see https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt And for RPM-based distributions there is https://yum.postgresql.org/

Answer (score 2):

> *Is there any other source where I can download only postgreSQL binaries for linux?*

You can use [BigSQL's](https://www.openscg.com/bigsql/package-manager/) command line client for that:

```
-bash-4.2$ python -c "$(curl -fsSL https://s3.amazonaws.com/pgcentral/install.py)"

Downloading BigSQL PGC 3.3.6 ...
Unpacking ...
Cleaning up
Setting REPO to https://s3.amazonaws.com/pgcentral
Updating Metadata

BigSQL PGC installed.  Try 'bigsql/pgc help' to get started.

-bash-4.2$ cd bigsql
-bash-4.2$ ./pgc download pg10

-bash-4.2$ ll -h
total 19M
drwxrwxr-x 4 zaphod users  115 Aug 29 15:50 conf
drwxr-xr-x 3 zaphod users   18 Aug 29 15:49 data
drwxrwxr-x 5 zaphod users   47 Mar  1 22:41 hub
drwxr-xr-x 2 zaphod users   27 Aug 29 15:49 logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 zaphod users  19M Aug 29 15:50 pg10-10.5-1-linux64.tar.bz2
-rwxrwxr-x 1 zaphod users 1.7K Mar  1 22:41 pgc
-bash-4.2$
```

The archive `pg10-10.5-1-linux64.tar.bz2` contains the following top-level directories:

```
pg10/lib/
pg10/init/
pg10/bin/
pg10/include/
pg10/share/
```

This can also be used to download a ZIP archive for Windows. "Installation" instructions for BigSQL on Windows can also be found in the above link.